# Example for using SoftLayer_Network_Storage:getNetworkMountAddress()

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can someone please give me an example of how to use the Softlayer REST API SoftLayer_Network_Storage:getNetworkMountAddress() for getting the mount address of my file storage?

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Try the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/7064305/getNetworkMountAddress

Method: Get
```

**Replace:** **$user**, **$apiKey** with your credentials and **7064305** with the storage that you would like to get its mount address